# Is it possible anyhow to raise system exception on catching exception manually?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, exception, sqlexception

I am writing a stored procedure where i m using try catch block.

Now i have a unique column in a table. When i try to insert duplicate value it throws exception with exception no 2627.

I want this to be done like this

if (exists(select * from tblABC where col1='value')=true)
raiseError(2627)--raise system error that would have thrown if i would have used insert query to insert duplicate value

**EDIT:**

I m using transaction which gets rollback on handling exception hence leading to increment of @@Identity value that got executed in previous queries b4 the exception occurred.

I want to check all such exception that could occur b4 actually inserting. For doing this, i would be checking for exception that could raise error manually using select statement with `if else`. Here i will be able to catch unique key violation but exception will not be occurred so i will be throwing exception deliberately here but that exception i want should be a system exception i.e error 2627

> And which method will be better, using
>   insert query or checking for duplicate
>   value before insertion using Select
>   query ?
>
> **IS IT POSSIBLE ANYHOW TO RAISE SYSTEM
>   EXCEPTION ON CATCHING EXCEPTION
>   MANUALLY i.e THROWING SAME EXCEPTION THAT SQL WOULD HAVE THROWN**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't raise system errors. RAISERROR(2627...) is illegal. Beside the fact that you're lying (no error 2627 occurred), you're missing the inserts into the message format.

Application should never rely on IDENTITY continuity, the fact that you complain that it 'increases the autoincrement' revels your application has a bug (in design for sure, if not in code). IDENTITY values may contain gaps, is part of their specifications.

As to what is better, to insert and catch, or to try to update: it depends on your prevalent pattern. If the value is likely to exist, the UPDATE first strategy is better. If the value is likely not to exist *or if the probability is unknown* it is better to INSERT and catch the error, for reasons of performance and, more importantly, correctness (SELECT check is never correct under concurrency).

Comment: @Remus Plz answer for my edit. sry for not getting descriptive information about my Ques

Comment: After your edit, my post needs nothing updated. Everything stands.

Comment: There are no re-throw semantics in T-SQL's TRY/CATCH. You have to throw a *new* exception, of custom type (ie. error code above 50000). It's messy, but that the state of the art in T-SQL exception handling.